# How to find the dependent dlls to run an EXE file created by a VC++ project

Tags: visual-c++, boost, opencv, exe

In my vc++ project I am using boost , OpenCv and JRTPLIB libraries , I have created an exe file and when i try to run it on another PC(the pc has no vc++ or the libraries mentioned) I get the error message...

"the application has failed to start because its side by side configuration is incorrect .please see the application event log or use the command line sxstrace.exe tool for details"

I am new to creating exe files and could you please help me in understanding the error. will there be dependencies which I need to copy with exe file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For running sxstrace.exe, go to Visual Studio command prompt and type sxstrace.exe.

Usage is as follows:

1. Before running your application, run sxstrace in trace mode:

   ```
   sxstrace.exe Trace -logfile:C:\MySxSTrace.log
   ```
2. Reproduce the error by starting your application
3. Now stop the trace by using the below command

   ```
    sxstrace.exe Parse -logfile:C:\MySxSTrace.log -outfile:C:\MySxSTrace.txt
   ```
4. Open output file from C:\MySxSTrace.txt

**What is Side by Side Configuration?**

A side-by-side assembly contains a collection of resources—a group of DLLs, Windows classes, COM servers, type libraries, or interfaces—that are always provided to applications together. These are described in the assembly manifest.

**Why is it Important?**

In many cases, it is possible to update existing applications to use side-by-side assemblies without having to change the application code. Developers are encouraged to use side-by-side assemblies to create isolated applications, and to update existing applications into isolated applications for the following reasons:

**Side-by-side** assemblies reduce the possibility of DLL version conflicts.

**Side-by-side** assembly sharing enables multiple versions of COM or Windows assemblies to run at the same time.

**Applications** and administrators can update assembly configuration on either a global or per-application configuration basis after deployment. For example, an application can be updated to use a side-by-side assembly that includes an update without having to reinstall the application.

for [Side by Side Configuration Incorrect](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43681/Side-by-Side-Configuration-Incorrect),read this Article...........
.